# check in viewWillAppear for tab clicks before refreshing

Tags: ios

I have 4 tabs in my application, one of my Tab loads a UIWebview which loads remote html contents. I have code to refresh content in "viewWillAppear" which will refresh the content when you navigate between tabs so far so good.

Here is my problem:

- When I click on Tab 1 ( UIWebView) and load an html form which has file upload input field as shown in the screen cap, upon clicking "Choose file" from html form will trigger actionsheet ( shown below)  "Take Photo/Video" , this will launch the camera after taking the picture and selecting it will force the UIWebview to refresh ( as the code to refresh is in **viewWillApper** which will trigger the refresh when coming from camera)  which is not right as I don't want my view to refresh when coming from Camera, can someone suggest if there is a way to check in viewWillApper if you are coming from Camera/Gallery or by clicking on tab. Thnx.

[image: WebView Screen Cap]

Comment: Did you check if the value of `self.presentedViewController` is not null when coming from the camera or gallery? This would be a solution to check if view appears for first time or because it was hidden by another controller

Comment: @DP2 Did it help? I am facing the very same issue.